# Server error (5xx) being reported by Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: php, wordpress

We are getting `Server error (5xx)` via our Google Search Console. Do you know why this is happening? And is there a solution to fix this?

When I checked error_log we found something like these:

```
[21-Aug-2019 06:11:11 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function twentysixteen_excerpt() in /home/teedupgolf/public_html/wp-content/themes/teedup/image.php on line 49
[21-Aug-2019 06:11:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function twentysixteen_excerpt() in /home/teedupgolf/public_html/wp-content/themes/teedup/image.php on line 49
[21-Aug-2019 06:12:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function twentysixteen_excerpt() in /home/teedupgolf/public_html/wp-content/themes/teedup/image.php on line 49
```

Most pages looks like automatically generated, here are the example pages:

```
https://teedupgolftours.com/2015/01/
https://teedupgolftours.com/category/uncategorized/
https://teedupgolftours.com/2015/07/
```

What we have done for now, we just disallow these links on `robots.txt`

Comment: Did you create the "teedup" theme? If it's based on the "twentysixteen" theme, maybe the `twentysixteen_excerpt` function was not copied or was deleted in the "teedup" theme. You can also look at `image.php` to check if that function is called on special conditions to see why it happens only for these pages

Comment: yes I think so, its twentysixteen maybe coz its heavy modified by their developer. Can't we just delete image.php?

Comment: Deleting the file will probably cause other errors. If you add the file's code to the question using the edit link, we'll be able to give you an advice on which code to comment.

Comment: I think I have sorted this issue already. Its on SEO by Yoast, we just turned yes to settings of Media & attachment URLs and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mistake.
If the site uses multiple languages, please use `hreflang` like the following example:

```
<link rel = "alternate" href = "https://smsreceive.site/Home/en" hreflang = "x-default" />
```